# Changing edge label background shading and shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Using tikz-network, I have generated network graphs. It seems edge labels leave a circular white background. When edge labels overlap it is not possible to read labels. I have tried following settings for edge styles: draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1}.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=0.950,y=0.950,size=1.8,color={44.0,160.0,44.0},RGB]{1111_0}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=4.030,size=1.078,color={227.0,119.0,194.0},RGB]{0111_1}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=2.490,size=0.819,color={188.0,189.0,34.0},RGB]{1011_1}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=5.570,size=1.467,color={44.0,160.0,44.0},RGB]{1101_1}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=7.110,size=0.835,color={227.0,119.0,194.0},RGB]{1110_1}
\Edge[,lw=0.035,label=0.035,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(1110_1)
\Edge[,lw=0.667,label=0.667,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(1101_1)
\Edge[,lw=0.278,label=0.278,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(0111_1)
\Edge[,lw=0.019,label=0.019,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(1011_1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this to avoid circular white shading of edge labels?

Output is as following:
[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is moving edge labels closer to their miffles an acceptable option. For example by changing `distance` from 0.1 to 0.3?

Comment: @Zarko, yes it just solves a problem for this instance but with interconnected layers of layers the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the `EdgeLabelStyle` is defined [with the `circle` shape](https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/blob/06a72d0c4f5eb91a451315c7f4382fdd7cdfbdf2/tikz-network.sty#L286).

If you change this by using

```
\tikzset{EdgeLabelStyle/.append style={shape=rectangle}}
```

you can get a better output:
[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\tikzset{EdgeLabelStyle/.append style={shape=rectangle}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=0.950,y=0.950,size=1.8,color={44.0,160.0,44.0},RGB]{1111_0}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=4.030,size=1.078,color={227.0,119.0,194.0},RGB]{0111_1}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=2.490,size=0.819,color={188.0,189.0,34.0},RGB]{1011_1}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=5.570,size=1.467,color={44.0,160.0,44.0},RGB]{1101_1}
\Vertex[x=12.975,y=7.110,size=0.835,color={227.0,119.0,194.0},RGB]{1110_1}
\Edge[,lw=0.035,label=0.035,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(1110_1)
\Edge[,lw=0.667,label=0.667,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(1101_1)
\Edge[,lw=0.278,label=0.278,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(0111_1)
\Edge[,lw=0.019,label=0.019,distance=0.1,style={sloped, draw opacity=1 ,fill opacity=0, text opacity=1},Direct](1111_0)(1011_1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

That said, the `graphs` library can do this, too.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\definecolor{greal}     {RGB}{ 44,160, 44} % somewhere between green and teal
\definecolor{darkyellow}{RGB}{188,189, 34}
\definecolor{purkle}    {RGB}{227,119,194} % somewhere between pink and purple
\tikzset{
  network/.style={
    graphs/every graph/.append style={
      no placement, empty nodes,
      edge quotes={
        sloped, fill=white, fill opacity=.9, text opacity=1,
        inner sep=+.1em, node font=\footnotesize, pos=.2},
      nodes=/tikz/network/vertex, edges=/tikz/network/edge}},
  network/vertex/.style={
    shape=circle, draw, fill=none, thick, inner sep=+0pt,
    size/.style={/pgf/minimum size={(##1)*1cm}}, size=1,
    /tikz/color/.style={/tikz/fill={##1}}},
  network/edge/.style={
    lw/.style={/tikz/line width={(##1)*1pt}},
    lwl/.style={
      /tikz/lw={##1}, /tikz/edge node={node[every edge quotes]{$##1$}}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[network]\graph{
  1111_0  [x=0.950, y=0.950, size=1.8,   color=greal] -- {
    0111_1[x=6.975, y=4.030, size=1.078, color=purkle,     > lwl = 0.278],
    1011_1[x=6.975, y=2.490, size=0.819, color=darkyellow, > lwl = 0.019],
    1101_1[x=6.975, y=5.570, size=1.467, color=greal,      > lwl = 0.667],
    1110_1[x=6.975, y=7.110, size=0.835, color=purkle,     > lwl = 0.035]
  }
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]